# ngOnChange not triggering even after trying all solutions

Tags: angular

i am trying to use ngOnChanges in order to update a string(even or odd) after another variable(counter) changes but the value of message stays '' and doesnt update when the counter changes.

```
export class CounterComponent{
  counter: number = 0;
  message: string = '';

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['counter']) {
      this.message = this.counter % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
    }
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }
}
```

```
      <div>
      <p>Counter: {{ counter }}</p>
      <p>Message: {{ message }}</p>
      <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
      <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
      </div>
```

Thank you for your time.

I have tried **all solutions ** i could find but nothing works, i have tried these :
1.

```
 @input counter: number = 0;
```

2. 

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.counter) {
      this.message = this.counter % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
    }
  }
```

3. 

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.counter.currentValue) {
      this.message = this.counter % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
    }
  }
```

4. 

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['counter'].currentValue) {
      this.message = this.counter % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your angular version is at least v17, just use `signal`, it automatically handle change detection. And try not to use `DoCheck` because it is a bad practice and may have perfomance issue.

Comment: Thanks alot !! I believe signal is the best option here since it automatically handles changes and it is a practical way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement this.

In your attempt to add `@Input() counter = 0`. To trigger `ngOnChanges`, you need to change the input from the parent component through databinding, which is why you didn't see it get triggered. As you were triggering it locally in the class instead.

The first way would be to switch out `OnChanges` with `DoCheck`, as `OnChanges` only runs when an `@Input` changes and your counter is not an `@Input`. So it would look something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'do-check',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Counter: {{ counter }}</p>
      <p>Message: {{ message }}</p>
      <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
      <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class DoCheckExample implements DoCheck {
  counter: number = 0;
  message: string = '';

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.message = this.counter % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use an `rxjs` `BehaviorSubject` to pass the data to the template when the value changes. This approach gives you more control of the flow of data for more advanced components/services/directives. It is also performs a lot less calculations than the previous approach, as that will run every time change detection runs. This only runs when the value is updated, and then a cachelike feature is used otherwise.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'event',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="counter$ | async as count">
      <p>Counter: {{ count.count }}</p>
      <p>Message: {{ count.msg }}</p>
      <button (click)="counter.next(count.count + 1)">Increment</button>
      <button (click)="counter.next(count.count - 1)">Decrement</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class EventExample {
  protected counter = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  counter$ = this.counter.pipe(
    map((i) => ({
      msg: i % 2 === 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd',
      count: i,
    })),
    tap(() => console.log('RxJS BehaviorSubject!'))
  );
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/docheck-verse-behaviorsubject?file=src%2Fmain.ts) of the two side-by-side (top is `ngDoCheck`, and the bottom is a `BehaviorSubject`). Open the console to see how many times each one outputs to the console. I added an interval in the main `App` that triggers once/second and doesn't do anything but still triggers `DoCheck`.

Comment: Thanks alot, this works, but in your first method, it keeps refreshing the value within the ngDoCheck whenever something changes in the component which could lead to unnecessery load time, how can i restrict this only when the counter changes ? just like in reacts useEffect hook for example, u could add an array at the end and whenever one variable changes, the useEffect refreshes.

Comment: That is why I suggested the second option. This is a lot less work for the browser and only runs when `next()` is called on `counter`. I don't know much about react, but I think this is similar.